# How to customise Indexpath.row value in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to retrieve only some of the index items in a table view.
eg: I have:

```
let array1 = ["one","two","three","four","two","one","three"] 
let array2 = ["dog","cat","lion","tiger","elephant","eagle","peacock"]

var duplicatedDict : [String:[Int]] = [:]
for (index,dateString) in array1.enumerated() {
    if(duplicatedDict[dateString] == nil){
        duplicatedDict[dateString] = [index]
    }else{
        duplicatedDict[dateString]?.append(index)
    }
}

print(duplicatedDict)
//output :  ["three": [2, 6], "four": [3], "one": [0, 5], "two": [1, 4]]
```

When I get the value "three" then I have to get only 2nd and 6th (2 and 6 is index value of the string "three" in array1) index of `array2`.

Output should be ("lion and peacock") in my UItableView row. How can I customise my tableview to get the above output?

Comment: I read this 3 times and still it didn't make sense, can you please try and rephrase?

Answer (score 0):

The generation of `duplicatedDict` can be greatly simplified using the new `default` parameter in Swift4:

```
let array1 = ["one","two","three","four","two","one","three"]
let array2 = ["dog","cat","lion","tiger","elephant","eagle","peacock"]

var duplicatedDict = [String:[Int]]()
for (index, val) in array1.enumerated() {
    duplicatedDict[ val, default:[] ].append(index)
}

print(duplicatedDict)
```

Once you have that, its easy to get the corresponding elements from `array2`:

```
if let indexes = duplicatedDict["three"] {
    let animals = indexes.map { array2[$0] }
    print(animals)
}
```

Comment: thank you @Gereon but i want to call this index in UITableView index how can i do that (index in UITableView is calling from 0th  and 1st index of array 2)